# Scala. Sangria.Print json schema

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I am using GraphQL on Scala via `Sangria`. Also I am using `apollo-codegen`.

I want to define my schema once, so I export my scheme from backend to frontend by:

```
schema.renderPretty
```

The problem is sangria's `renderPretty` prints schema in `schemaAst` format. But `apollo-codegen` expects `json` format.

How to make `sangria` render schema in json format? Or maybe painless convert `schemaAst` to `json` via `SBT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are referring to the introspection JSON. With Sangria you can get it by executing an introspection query:

```
Executor.execute(schema, sangria.introspection.introspectionQuery)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get `String`, not `Future` like `renderPretty` do?

Comment: You get a `Future[Json]` as a result of the execution. You can `Await` on this future, but at the moment is not possible to to get sync result.

Comment: I got it. Thank you